# How can I search 10 OUs in parallel using DirectoryServices

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I need to query LDAP on multiple paths and I wish to use DirectoryServices for various reasons.

```
var ADobjects = new Dictionary<string, ADobject>();

foreach (var OUItem in OUs)
{
    using (DirectoryEntry ldap = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + OUItem))
    {
        using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(ldap))
        {
            searcher.Filter = "(objectClass=user)";
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");

            using (SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll())
            {
                foreach (SearchResult result in results)
                {
                    var dn = result.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString();
                    if (!ADobjects.ContainsKey(dn))
                    {
                        ADobjects.Add(dn, new ADobject(result));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works.. but when I have 10 OU's to query I would like to launch these queries in parallel.

I know how to launch an async method (more or less) but how can I use these queries to fill 1 dictionary at the same time??

I've clicked around but I'm really unsure if this can and should be done async. Since every search might take a few seconds, it could really benefit from async tasks.

Comment: Give them separate dictionary to work with, when they are done merge those dictionaries. See [Fork join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93join_model).

Comment: What have you done so far to try to leverage parallelism?  What problems have you had with those implementations?

Answer (score 0):

You can use futures http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963556.aspx

example from mentioned source:

```
    int BufferSize = ...
    var buffer1 = new BlockingCollection<string>(BufferSize);

    var f = new TaskFactory(TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, 
                                                         TaskContinuationOptions.None);

    var stage1 = f.StartNew(() => LdapSearch(buffer1));
    var stage2 = f.StartNew(() => LdapSearch(buffer1));
    var stage3 = f.StartNew(() => LdapSearch(buffer1));
    var stage4 = f.StartNew(() => LdapSearch(buffer1));

    Task.WaitAll(stage1, stage2, stage3, stage4);

static void LdapSearch(BlockingCollection<string> output,
                        )
{

      output.Add(some result);

}
```

Comment: This code will break as you are repeatedly informing the collection that items won't be added, and then trying to add more items.